# Setting a property in another VC by using presentViewController method

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, segue, viewcontroller

I am trying to set a `.text` properties in another viewController class but it does not get set. how can I achieve this result without using a segue?

```
AccountTypeVC *vc = (AccountTypeVC *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AccountTypeVC"];
AccountTypeVC.serviceTitle.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The `.h` of `AccountTypeVC`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *serviceTitle;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary that after `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` all the UI elements are initialised. Recommended is to bind all the UI elements with data once the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller has been called.

Add another property in `AccountTypeVC`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *serviceTitleText;
```

And set it to label in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.serviceTitle.text = self. serviceTitleText;
}
```

And set `serviceTitleText` property instead of label before presenting the `AccountTypeVC`.

```
AccountTypeVC *vc = (AccountTypeVC *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AccountTypeVC"];
vc.serviceTitleText = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: I now changed the NSString to NSMutableArray and it wont work why?